# Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`

Tags: angular

Hi any idea on how to prevent

error  Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`  @typescript-eslint/unbound-method

```
16:41  error  Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`  @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
  16:62  error  Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`  @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
  17:34  error  Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`  @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
  18:35  error  Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`  @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
  18:56  error  Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`  @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
  20:40  error  Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`  @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
  21:46  error  Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`  @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormControl, FormGroup, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  registrationForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registrationForm = new FormGroup({
      companyName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormGroup({
        password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]),
        repeatPassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
      }, {validators: [this.passwordMismatchValidator()]})
    });
  }

  onRegistrationFormSubmit() {
    if (!this.registrationForm.valid) {
      return;
    }
  }

  passwordMismatchValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const password = c.get('password')?.value;
      const repeatPassword = c.get('repeatPassword')?.value;

      if (password !== repeatPassword) {
        return {'passwordMismatch': true};
      }

      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, does anyone have a fresh solution for this ESLint issue?

Answer (score 19):

See [this issue](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1929). It seems that you must do one of the following:

> - the Angular library changes from a static method, to a static arrow    function property.
> - the Angular library annotates its functions with something like `this: void` which we can build handling for in this rule.
> - you, the user, disable comments.

For the time being I guess the only solution consists in either disabling the rule entirely on the line/file/project level or in changing the severity from error to simple warning.

For the former case, just add the following:

- before the line that gives you the error (to disable the error just on that line):

  ```
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
  ```
- at the top of the file where the error is shown (to disable the error in the whole file):

  ```
  /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/unbound-method */
  ```

  you can also enable it again in the same file if you want to only skip a section by putting the following line:

  ```
  /* eslint-enable @typescript-eslint/unbound-method */
  ```
- in the `rules` section of your eslint configuration file (i.e. `.eslintrc.json`) (to disable the error in the whole project):

  ```
  "@typescript-eslint/unbound-method": "off"
  ```

In the latter case, put the following in the `rules` section of your eslint configuration file (i.e. `.eslintrc.json`) (to show a warning instead of an error in the whole project):

```
"@typescript-eslint/unbound-method": "warn"
```

**EDIT:** for the Angular `Validators.*`, you can alternatively overwrite the rule in your eslint configuration file (see [the documentation](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/unbound-method.md#example)):

```
"@typescript-eslint/unbound-method": [
    "error",
    {
        "ignoreStatic": true
    }
],
```

Comment: `"ignoreStatic": true` seems to be the best solution at the moment.